# postgresql port confusion 5433 or 5432?

Tags: postgresql, port, psql

I have installed postgresql on OSX. When I run psql, I get

```
$ psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5433"?
```

However, from /etc/services

```
postgresql      5432/udp    # PostgreSQL Database
postgresql      5432/tcp    # PostgreSQL Database
#                          Tom Lane <tgl@sss.pgh.pa.us>
pyrrho          5433/tcp    # Pyrrho DBMS
pyrrho          5433/udp    # Pyrrho DBMS
```

5433 is occupied by pyrrho, 5432 is assigned to pg. I can connect with

```
psql -p 5432
```

but why does psql think it is 5433 and how do I make psql look in the right place by default?

Comment: Check if the environment variable `PGPORT` is defined: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html

Answer (score 236, accepted):

`/etc/services` is only advisory, it's a listing of well-known ports. It doesn't mean that anything is actually running on that port or that the named service will run on that port.

In PostgreSQL's case it's typical to use port 5432 if it is available. If it isn't, most installers will choose the next free port, usually 5433.

You can see what is actually running using the `netstat` tool (available on OS X, Windows, and Linux, with command line syntax varying across all three).

This is further complicated on Mac OS X systems by the horrible mess of different PostgreSQL packages - Apple's ancient version of PostgreSQL built in to the OS, Postgres.app, Homebrew, Macports, the EnterpriseDB installer, etc etc.

What ends up happening is that the user installs Pg and starts a server from one packaging, but uses the `psql` and `libpq` client from a different packaging. Typically this occurs when they're running Postgres.app or homebrew Pg and connecting with the `psql` that shipped with the OS. Not only do these sometimes have different default ports, but the Pg that shipped with Mac OS  X has a different *default unix socket path*, so even if the server is running on the same port it won't be listening to the same unix socket.

Most Mac users work around this by just using tcp/ip with `psql -h localhost`. You can also specify a port if required, eg `psql -h localhost -p 5433`. You might have multiple PostgreSQL instances running so make sure you're connecting to the right one by using `select version()` and `SHOW data_directory;`.

You can also  specify a unix socket directory; check the `unix_socket_directories` setting of the PostgreSQL instance you wish to connect to and specify that with `psql -h`, e.g.`psql -h /tmp`.

A cleaner solution is to correct your system `PATH` so that the `psql` and `libpq` associated with the PostgreSQL you are actually running is what's found first on the `PATH`. The details of that depend on your Mac OS X version and which Pg packages you have installed. I don't use Mac and can't offer much more detail on that side without spending more time than is currently available.

Answer (score 30):

Quick answer on OSX, set your environment variables.

```
>export PGHOST=localhost

>export PGPORT=5432
```

Or whatever you need.

Answer (score 24):

The default port of Postgres is commonly configured in:

```
sudo vi /<path to your installation>/data/postgresql.conf
```

On Ubuntu this might be:

```
sudo vi /<path to your installation>/main/postgresql.conf
```

Search for `port` in this file.

Comment: On Mac OSX with the BigSQL distro it is here: `~/PostgreSQL/data/pg96`

Answer (score 12):

It seems that one of the most common reasons this happens is if you install a new version of PostgreSQL without stopping the service of an existing installation. This was a particular headache of mine, too. Before installing or upgrading, particularly on OS X and using the one click installer from Enterprise DB, make sure you check the status of the old installation before proceeding.

Comment: Yes, we installed postgresql-9.5 when 9.4 was already installed, so 9.5 chose 5433 as the default port

Comment: I've used 5432 & 5433 for long time, I've seen 5436 but no idea if that just someone creativity or some default on different os-es.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to [@a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100368/postgresql-port-confusion-5433-or-5432#comment21244421_15100368), I changed my PGPORT definition to 5432 in pg_env.sh. That fixed the problem for me. I don't know why postgres set it as 5433 initially when it was hosting the service at 5432.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem as well, it ended up that I had two postgres servers running at the same time. I uninstalled one of them and changed the port back to 5432 and works fine now.

Answer (score 4):

For me in **PgAdmin 4** on **Mac OS High Sierra**, Clicking the **PostrgreSQL10** database under **Servers** in the left column, then the **Properties** tab, showed **5433** as the port under **Connection**. (I don't know why, because I chose 5432 during install). Anyway, I clicked the **Edit** icon under the **Properties** tab, change that to **5432**, saved, and that solved the problem. Go figure.

Comment: All that does is allow you to connect to the server already running on 5432, which is why you could connect after doing that.  The server was running on 5432 per your installation as you correctly stated.