# role does not exist and syntax error for inserting query in NodeJs into postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I've created a table with the name of `user` in postgres which contains `id, name, family` columns (id is auto-increment). The query which I want to insert into the postgres likes the following:

```
var config = {
    user: 'username',
    database: 'databaseName',
    password: 'password',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    max: 10,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
};

const pool = new postgre.Pool(config);
let query = "INSERT INTO user(name, family) VALUES ('name', 'family')";
pool.query(query, [], function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error("error running query", err);
    }
    console.log("done!");        
});
```

But, I've got the following error:

> Syntax error near user

Also, I have tried different approach to send the request liked the following:

```
const connectionString = "http://localhost:5432/databaseName?username=username&password=password";
const client = new postgre.Client(connectionString);
client.connect();
const query = client.query("INSERT INTO user(id, name, family) VALUES ('name', 'family')");
query.then(x => { console.log("done!")});
query.catch(x => { console.log(x)});
```

But I've got the following error:

> role \"UserName\" does not exist

Also, the `UserName` (name of the server) in the body of the error is not the same as the `username` of the database.

I've checked the all possible fallacies such as the correctness of the username and password.

Therefore, the question is what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these problems come from the table name. As mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919391/postgresql-error-fatal-role-username-does-not-exist), the name of `user` is a reserved name in postgres. Therefore, these errors will be passed if change the name of the `user` table such as `users`.

Comment: Renaming the table isn't the best solution. See the answer I posted ;)

Comment: @vitaly-t I saw this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919391/postgresql-error-fatal-role-username-does-not-exist before. Indeed, I found the solutions, but mentioned here as a problem can be seen from the other window. In addition, for my case changing the name of the table is better. Anyhow, thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

`user` is a reserved word in PostgreSQL that refers to the currently logged in user. For that reason, in order to be able to use a table with name `user`, the name must always be inside double quotes - `"user"`.

Answer (score 0):

> role "UserName" does not exist

Node shows the exact same error, even in the event of failure to establish a connection to the postgresql instance.

Since the Username and Password pair was already verified, ensuring the validity of `DATABASE_HOST` and `DATABASE_PORT` variables would be a good place to start, as [Postgresql uses ports `5432` and `5433` interchangably.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100368/postgresql-port-confusion-5433-or-5432)

Further more, Unix sockets can be set as node's `DATABASE_HOST` simply via `localhost` or it can be explicitly mentioned to the directory where the socket is located (usually at `/var/lib/postgresql` or `/tmp` for BSD systems) and Node will automatically find the socket name (looks like this: `.s.PGSQL.5433`), based on the configured `DATABASE_PORT` variable.

[Same issue mentioned at the core pg module Github repo](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1647)